# How do I dynamically show the availability of a certain book via ISBN number in PHP while issuing a book?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Here is the check.php file which I'am calling in another .php file
for issuing a book. Also, I have another code where there is no issue with showing the book name automatically when I input the ISBN number.

```
<?php 
    require_once("includes/config.php");
    if(!empty($_POST["bookid"])) {
      $bookid=$_POST["bookid"];

        $sql ="SELECT BookQuantity,id FROM tblbooks WHERE (ISBNNumber=:bookid)";
    $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':bookid', $bookid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> execute();
    $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
    {
      foreach ($results as $result) {?>


    <?php  
    if($BookQuantity == 0)
    {
        echo"<b>AVAILABLE</b>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"<b>Not Available</b>";
    }


     echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',false);</script>";
    }
    }
     else{?>

    <option class="others"> Invalid Reference Number</option>
    <?php
     echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>";
    }
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: From where you are getting the value of `$BookQuantity`?

Comment: @Saral I got it from table tblbooks. i have used the select command above

Comment: You are fetching as object. You need to assign the appropriate value of `BookQuantity` to `$BookQuantity` variable.

Comment: @Saral Right .. and how do I do that?

Comment: Do `$BookQuantity = $results->BookQuantity`.

Comment: @Saral I changed the code as you said... And Now it is showing the bookquantity and all properly, but still for a book having quantity as more than 0 , it is still showing NOT AVAILABLE , that is it is not executing the if condition properly...

Comment: @Saral Okay I did some further changes and now my question is solved .. Thank You